# Apple Pay/Stripe Error in Processing Payments

Tags: php, ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm trying to process stripe payments through Apple Pay but keep getting this error:

> Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "There was an error communicating with your payment backend" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There was an error communicating with your payment backend}

Checking payments log on Stripe though it is coming back as 200 OK

[image: Stripe Image]

The payments don't seem to appear on stripe however so I'm wondering why this error comes about. Included my backend PHP below:

```
<?php

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("SECRET KEY");

token ID submitted by the form: $token = $_POST['stripeToken']; $mount
= $_POST['amount'];

if($token == "" || $amount == ""){

    echo "No Token or Amount Set"   return;

}

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(   "amount" => $amount,   "currency" => "gbp",   "description" => "Example charge",   "source"
=> $token, ));
>
```

EDIT

After a bit more digging I found that the status code return was 500. How would I go about debugging this? Is this common?